# Wrong counterexample to $[0,1]^\omega$ with product topology being not limit point compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, analysis, compactness

The space $X$ is called limit point compact if every infinite subset $E$ of $X$ has a limit point. It can also be proved that (open cover) compactness implies limit point compactness.

Let $[0,1]^\omega$ have the product topology. Clearly $[0,1]^\omega$ is compact, so therefore it should be limit point compact. But the infinite subset $\{(1,0,0,0,...),(0,1,0,0,...),(0,0,1,0,...),(0,0,0,1,...),...\}$ doesn't seem to have a limit point.

I have a suspicion that $(0,0,0,0,...)$ is a limit point of this set. But how do you show this formally? We can easily find an open set around $(0,0,0,0,...)$ which does not contain any sequence with a $1$ in it.

Comment: How can we "easily find" such an open set?

Comment: I was thinking $[0,\frac12)^{\omega}$ but I just found out that is not open in the product topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a neighborhood of $(0,0,...)$. Inside that neighborhood there is an open set $U$ of the form $U_1\times U_2\times ...\times U_N\times [0,1]^\omega$, where $U_i$ are open neighborhoods of $0$ in $[0,1]$.

Then all elements of the sequence that have index larger than $N$ are in $U$.

Your last sentence contains a misunderstanding of the definition of the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition).
I suspect that you are thinking that neighborhoods of $(0,0,...)$ can be for the form $U_1\times U_2\times U_3,...$ where the $U_i$ are arbitrary open neighborhoods of $0$ in $[0,1]$. However, note that in the product topology only finitely many of those $U_i$ can be different from $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is relevant when  $ 1 \notin U_i$ for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant N$, right?

Comment: @OlivierRoche It doesn't matter. There is no need for $N$ to be the smallest possible or not.

Comment: You are correct, thanks.

Comment: Wow, I should have actually looked up what the product topology was, I just assumed it was the same as the box topology, thanks.

Comment: @MuscovyWschodnie in the box topology this product is neither compact nor limit point compact. And not connected either. The box topology is actually quite “ugly” that way: products then hardly have any “nice” properties.